# Dequeue a style file which is making website load slow!

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I have a website running on GrandNews WordPress Theme (https://themeforest.net/item/grand-news-news-magazine/15885465) and loading via KeyCDN. The site is loading a CSS file located at websitedomain.kxcdn.com/wp-content/themes/grandnews/modules/kirki/assets/css/kirki-styles.css which is of 0KB size and not in use. This file "kirki-styles.css" is making website load slow as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/qoho6e and CDN support suggested me to dequeue the stylesheet in a child theme functions.php file which I tried to but somehow it's not working and server still try to load file and gives 504 error.

Maybe something wrong with my code. So far I have followed these steps:

1. Created a Child Theme and tested it... It's working.
2. Tried following pieces of code to try to make it to work
   (Nothing extra)

   ```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kirki_style_remove', 100);
       function kirki_style_remove()
       {
           wp_dequeue_style('/wp-content/themes/grandnews/modules/kirki/assets/css/kirki-styles.css');
       }
   ```

   Tried this way once as well:

   ```
   function wp_dequeue_kirki_style()
   {
       wp_dequeue_style('kirki-styles', 'websitedomain.kxcdn.com/wp-content/themes/grandnews/modules/kirki/assets/css/kirki-styles.css');
       // wp_deregister_style('kirki-styles');
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_dequeue_kirki_style', '999');
   ```

Apart from these two codes above, I also tried a plugin but that didn't work as well.

Please advise with the most efficient solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
function wp_dequeue_kirki_style()
{

    wp_dequeue_style('kirki-styles');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_dequeue_kirki_style');
```

Please make sure that you have handler name `kirki-styles` in the parent theme for the css file that you want to remove. Because `wp_dequeue_style` function used handler as parameter. You can check documentaion of dequeue function here => https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/

Comment: thanks for your help... It did worked: http://prntscr.com/qoihtt I was putting the handler name wrong. You are a life saver :)

Comment: Actually no, it's back again (though a few minutes back it was not there). I can still see the issue (504 and too much time to load) in Private Window :(

Comment: Please clear all the caches and check using view page source is the file loading or not?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. So, I tried clearning cache multiple times but issue was still there. Then I disabled the cache plugin which fixed the issue as you asked the file is still getting included in the source: http://prntscr.com/qojvwb and console: http://prntscr.com/qojw6f. However, the difference which I have noticed is that it's not coming from CDN (not a CDN path like it was earlier). May be because of disabling cache plugin WP Fastest Cache has stopped calling CDN version of the file?